# At which rate does visible matter decrease from the galatic center?

Tags: galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

At which rate does the visible matter density in galaxies decrease when moving away from the galactic center?

Comment: You mean something like this: http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys443/lectures/gal_1/petro/petro.html? That is the light emission, of course, which comes from stellar populations and is modulated by dust etc.. If you are thinking about actual density, that's dominated by dark matter in most galaxies, and it can be measured (assuming Newtonian gravity holds) with the rotation curve.

Comment: In which direction? Once you get out of the Bulge, very different behavior if you go up out of the disk, or if you stay within the disk...

Comment: @rfl in the disk

Comment: @FlatterMann The link you provided is light intensity, not matter or energy density.

Comment: We can't measure matter density directly. We can only measure light intensity (including spectra to detect gas and dust) and gravitational interaction. From those we can derive matter density estimates. Non-baryonic dark matter, if it exists, can only be measured by its gravity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say "in the disk", I'll assume you mean "how does the density of normal matter decrease from the center in the disk of spiral galaxies", so I'll ignore the question of how the decrease works in, say, elliptical galaxies.

The simple answer is "as an approximately exponential function of the radius":

$\rho(R) \propto \rho_{0} \exp(-R/h)$,

where $\rho_{0}$ is the density at the center of the disk, $R$ is the radius, and $h$ is the "scale length" of the disk. (The scale length is how far it takes for the density to fall by a factor of $e$; for the Milky Way, this is about 3 kiloparsecs, or 10,000 light years.)

More precisely: this is how the density of *stars* usually decreases. The density of *gas* usually decreases in a similar fashion, although often more slowly (larger scale length) than the stars.

(This is ignoring complications like "what if there is a nuclear star cluster or a bulge in the center?", local deviations due to spiral arms or bars, and changes in the exponential scale length at large radii, as in disk "truncations" or "antitrucations".)